# get total number of files from FetchHDFS processor

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

is thr a way to get total number of files from single run of FetchHDFS processor?

my use-case is ==> read all files from a directory (hdfs), concat them and then do further processing. But to halt merge processor (till all files are in queue), so I need file count to set "Minimum Number of Entries".

I can use wait/notify, but then I still need total count so set flags correctly.

In any case, doesn't it sound logical to have this as an attribute for FetchHDFS or any file listing processor.

Update#2 (merge Processor) As per the configuration, merge processor should let file go every 300 sec. In my usecase, total input files are 2000, but they are coming in slow place (approx 200 sec). So below configuration should be good enough to merge all the file. But it is not working. I can still see merge processor letting files go in much smaller interval.
[image]

**Update #3**  == total size of all 1600 file is 318 KB, which is far less than bin size 128 MB

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListHDFS/FetchHDFS` doesn't provide the number of files picked up in a particular run. You can, however use `ExecuteScript` or `UpdateAttribute` and with the help of `Wait/Notify`, and make it work.

The simplest solution I would suggest is, `MergeContent` also takes one optional property called `Max Bin Age`, you can configure some time units here, like `2 mins` or `30 secs` and set `Minimum Number of Entries` to some higher number. This way, regardless of the queue size not matching the configured number in `Min. number of entries`, once the time configured for `Max bin age` elapses, those queued files will be picked up and merged together. This might require some assumptions and experimentation to get the correct configuration done though.

Comment: I configured merge processor to a higher limit, so all files can be clubbed (I have updated my original question). It is not working.

Comment: That is because 'Max. Group Size' is configured.

Comment: When you configure `Min. Group Size` and `Max. Group Size`, the flowfiles that execeed the Max size will be processed in its own bin so that is the reason why you're seeing some smaller number of files merged together.

Comment: total size of all flowfiles (1600) is ~300 KB. and size of bucket is 128 MB, so not sure why Merge processor will let smaller group go. I am expecting 1 merge, i am ending up with 178. see update#3 (in original post).

Comment: I don't have complete knowledge on the `Min. Group Size` and `Max. Group Size` properties. I had some weird experiences using them. My use cases never had a need to have those properties configured. I would suggest you to write to `users@nifi.apache.org` to get more clarity.

Comment: finally worked. `Minimum Number of Entries = 1` rest values remains same as screenshot in update#3 (original post). Thanks for ur suggestion. It did helped me with issue, although getting filecount from listHDFS/File is still a far fetched dream :(